# business catalyst classification

Tags: csv, business-catalyst

**Business Catalyst Web App Import Classifications Column**

This is slightly bizarre question which I am hoping someone can help me with. I've created a Web App in my clients Business Catalyst system. The web app will have many items all classified to appear on one or multiple pages.

Column J in the CSV file to be imported into Business Catalyst is the 'Classifications' column which allows you to assign a Category to the item. This is all well and good except I cannot appear to assign multiple categories to each item. I have attempted to differentiate each category by a comma without a space, with a space, using a pipe and splitting it over 2 lines...to no avail.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this, I don't want their Web Administrator to have to manually assign the categories if I can help it.

Answer (score 5):

After adding three classifications (a.k.a. categories) to a web app item, then exporting it, the following text was in the Classifications column:

```
/Solutions;/Customers;/Products/Sub Products;
```

The classifications were:

- 'Solutions'
- 'Customers'
- 'Sub Products' (a child of 'Products')

Changing the Classifications by hand, then re-uploading the .csv file, successfully resulted in the item's classifications being updated.

Note: Don't forget to change the format of any date fields (especially the Expiry Date) to use a four digit year format, before you save or export back to csv format. The default expiry date is 9999-01-01, which is interpreted as 1999-01-01 if it it saved with a two digit year. BC's default date format appears to be in the format 01-Jan-9999.